# Проверка на равность двух чисел

Tags: c, алгоритм, c++

Подскажите, алгоритм проверки на равность двух double-чисел до определенной позиций после точки.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (abs(A-B) < eps) { 
    //равны
}
```

eps - точность (0.0001 - 4 знака после запятой)

A, B - числа

Comment: Блин, точно! Списибо )