# Вывод дробной части от логарифма C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Необходимо определить, является ли логарифм a по основанию b целым.
Мое решение: 
`cout<<fmod(log(a)/log(b),1);`
Но, например, при тесте a=46656 b=6, программа выдает `8.88178e-016`, вместо ожидаемого `0`. 
Как это можно исправить / реализовать другим способом?

Comment: 1. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/50492/178988 2. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/399420/178988 3. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461464/178988

Comment: Хотя в данном вопросе, возможно, следует поступить вообще по-другому.

Comment: Для целых значений - просто возведите в степень и проверьте...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логарифм является целым тогда и только тогда, когда число является степенью основания.

Операции с дробными числами вносят в вычисления погрешность, поэтому, если по условию даны целые числа (в смысле, они хранятся в целочисленных переменных), то имеет смысл не жалеть 32 операции чтобы просто проверить соответствующие степени:

```
bool check(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
  unsigned x;
  for (x=1; x<a; x*=b);
  return x==a;
}
```

При необходимости стоит подумать о переполнении.